# How to extract a piece of text from PDF with unknown patterns?

Tags: python, pdf, text, automation, text-extraction

I am trying to grab one specific section from multiple PDF files using a Python script with `pdfminer.six`.

The problems I'm facing are as below (I tried the techniques below but to no avail).

1. The extracted section does not have any regular expression patterns (generic text).
2. Its index is not fixed (e.g., does not always start at line 10 or end at 100).
3. If using x-y coordinates, margin-left and right are fixed, but there can be an unknown amount of paragraphs before the target section.
4. In the original PDF files, the section is defined by its respective title and readable to human eyes, but the relative position of the anchor point **can be** lost after text extraction (shown in the example below).

```py
# There are 2 different PDF files with the content as below
Line 1
Line 2
Line ...
Important section title
- Section content - I want this

# Here is extracted text, which is then saved to .txt file
# The first file
Line 1
Line 2
Line ...
Important section title
- Section content - I want this # 1 line below the section title, this is an expected result

# The second file
Line 1 Important section title
Line 2 
- Section content - I want this # Title and content are not in order anymore, so relative position is not reliable
Line ...
```

Any suggestion for an approach to overcome these is appreciated!

Comment: How would **you** identify the section in the PDF if there are no anchor points for it and the position is unknown?

Comment: In an original PDF file, it is defined by the section title, which is readable to human eyes. However, the title and content order can be mixed after text extraction so the anchor point is lost (as shown in the example). If using layout analysis (coordinates), the section position is not fixed because there can be an unknown amount of paragraphs before it.

Comment: Is it styled to look like a “title”? Can you share some samples?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share the real samples, either redacted or not (internal documents). I also don't have access to the PDF creation procedure so I cannot recreate a minimal sample. The title is styled differently compared to other text (bold and bigger size).